# Polymorphism: method is changed, but argument value not

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

**I ran following code:**

```
public class Cycling {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Cycle unicycle      = new Unicycle();
        System.out.println("Unicycle name: " + unicycle.name);
        unicycle.ride();
    }
}

class Cycle {
    public String name = "cycle";
    public void ride() {
        System.out.println("Ride cycle!");
    }
}

class Unicycle extends Cycle{
    public String name = "unicycle";
    public void ride() {
        System.out.println("Ride unicycle!");
    }
}
```

**I expected this output:**

*Unicycle name: unicycle*

*Ride unicycle!*

**I got this output:**

*Unicycle name: cycle*

*Ride unicycle!*

Method was successfully changed, but value of the argument was not. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic. `unicycle.name` is referring to the `name` in `Cycle` because it's accessed via an expression of type `Cycle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is polymorphic, your field is not - because fields are not polymorphic.

You currently have 2 fields with the same name, one field is shadowing another. When you do:

```
Cycle unicycle = new Unicycle();
```

`Cycle` has no idea about the `name` in the `Unicycle` class. So when you do  `unicycle.name`, it refers to the one in `Cycle` class.

---

Advise: always keep your fields private.

---

An IDE like IntelliJ Idea would have highlighted this error.

Comment: "Advise: always keep your fields private." - I know that, but I made it public to create this example.

Comment: @JakovKusić - okay, sounds good. Then this comment is for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

This is classic case of compile-time vs runtime polymorphism.

Compiler resolves the variables during compile time but methods are resolved by JVM during run time.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because when you define a variable of the same name in the subclass, it will have both properties that only share their name. This is called **hiding**. If you want to access the value of the superclass variable "name", you can call it by `super.name`.

As you can see, that the variables are handled completely on their own, they can also have a completely different type.